# Find the pair than minimizes the value of a function with two parameters

Tags: algorithm, search

I have an function F(x, y) where x and y are integers and two arrays a, b with n elements each. I need to find two numbers i, j which make the value of F(a[i], b[j]) minimum. Is there a better aproach than searching all the n^2 different combinations? The function F returns a different value for different parameters.

EDIT: In my problem the arrays a, b represent n cannonballs fired by two opposing armies in two points of a straight line, starting at time=0. The function is an oracle that returns the exact time that two of them collide and I need to find the couple that collides first. If they do not collide the oracle returns the time that they would collide if there were no other cannonballs.

Comment: 1. It's really hard to help you without any information about the function, do you know something about it?
2. What do you know about the arrays? are they sorted? anything else?
3. It really depends on the answers of the 2 previous questions, but you might want to check out "Genetic algorithm"

Comment: @T.G. sorry for the lack of info, I edited the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your oracle always returns a time when the cannonballs collide, I assume that they are shot directly at each other. They are all shot at time `t = 0`, so the only variable is the velocity. We can get the fastest cannonball in `a` by just finding the best `i` which minimizes the value `F(a[i], b[c])`, where `c` is a constant, e.g. `0`, then we find the solution by comparing this `bestI` to all values in `b` to find the best `j`, which minimizes `F(a[bestI], b[j])`. This is O(n). Like this you also get the value of the minimum, if you only need the best `i` and `j` you could again just find the minimum `F(a[c], b[j])`, where `c` is a constant again.